# Using Oracle how do I conditionally select a column from two different tables based on two difference if statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I need to conditionally select a column from two different if statements and two different tables.  In short, it looks like this in pseudo-code:

```
IF  
    TABLE_A.COLUMN_A = ‘ABC’ THEN TABLE_A.COLUMN_B 
ELSE IF 
    TABLE_B.COLUMN_F <>  0 THEN TABLE_C.COLUMN_C
END IF
```

How might someone do this in Oracle sql?

TIA

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your question is too sketchy.  You reference multiple tables and it is entirely unclear how they are related.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` might help, if these tables are somehow related (i.e. you can `JOIN` them (would a `CROSS JOIN` be an option?):

```
select case when a.column_a = 'ABC' then a.column_b 
            when b.column_f <> 0    then c.column_c
       end
from table_a a join table_b b on ...
               join table_c c on ...
where ...
```

Comment: These tables are remotely joined through multiple other tables.  The entire SQL statement is about 2 pages long including joining about 12 tables from which these two are included.

Comment: OK. Well, then yes, CASE might be what you want.

Comment: Given that these tables are already joined in the main SQL, do I still need to do the join in this subquery?

Comment: I don't think so. you'd just use CASE part of query I suggested.